# WordPress generated shortcode attribute not running

Tags: php, wordpress, api

Here i am trying to pass amount from shortcode to the url. Whenever i try to change the value of amount from shortcode it's not changing. It shows the default value only i.e of amount 1

Here's the code

```
function currency_conversion_shortcode($atts)
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'amount' => '1',
    ), $atts, 'currency_conversion' );
    $url = "https://api.fastforex.io/convert?from=AED&to=NPR&amount=" . $atts['amount'] . "&api_key=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx";

    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    return $result['result']['rate'] . " NPR";
}

add_shortcode('currency_conversion', 'currency_conversion_shortcode');
```

Comment: might be something to do with `'amount' => '1',`

Comment: how are you using the shortcode? I assume something like `[currency_conversion amount="50"]`

Comment: exactly that @zanderwar

Comment: To be clear, you are inspecting `$atts['amount']` and not the result of the API call, right? Also, it might be worth it to change the third to `shortcode_atts` to something else just to make sure that other code isn't filtering it. Similarly to that, you can also use that third parameter with an `apply_filter` call to inject missing default values at the end if you want.

Comment: (Making an API call on _every_ page view is probably not a good idea. Depending on how often the data changes and how "current" you need it to be, you should think about implementing some caching. WP Transients are good for that.)

Comment: Or perhaps caching IS the issue and it needs to be cleared?